# Not getting json response from openweather api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to get current weather from http://openweathermap.org/ . First I get the latitude and longitude using html5 geolocation api. I am able to do this successfully. Next I tried to make a ajax call to openweather to get the current weather conditions using ajax, but the ajax call is not successful. Here is my code. Please help me identify the issue.

```
window.onload = getLocation();

function getLocation()
{
   if(navigator.geolocation) {
     // The coordinate object of the  location is passed to the displayWeathe function
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayWeather);
   }
   else { // geolocation not supported
     var msg = document.getElementById("content");

     msg.innerHTML = "Geolocation not supported in your browser!!";
   }
}
function displayWeather(position) {
  // Get the Latitude and Longitude
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  // url for openweather api
  var url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+latitude+"&lon="+longitude+"&APPID=<my_key>";
  alert(url);

  // get weather from OpenWeather Map
  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url,
    method:"GET",
    jsonCallback: 'jsonp',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
       alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(data) {
      alert("OOPS");
    }
  });
```

I also tried this instead of the ajax call. This is also not working.

```
$.getJSON(url,function(json){
    alert("Success");
  }).fail( function(json, textStatus, error) {
        alert("getJSON failed, status: " + textStatus + ", error: "+error)
 });
```

The URL is correct and it I get JSON response when I copy paste the URL in browser. You can see live demo [here](http://codepen.io/JanakyMurthy/full/LxqvVB/)

Comment: live demo says `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement`

Comment: your url needs to have `http://` at the beginning of it - otherwise it's relative to the page making the request!

Comment: @JaromandaX It is not showing that message for me . I am getting the 'OOPS' message

Comment: look in the console

Comment: `window.onload = getLocation();` should be `window.onload = getLocation;`

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank You so much!! It's working now. I did not notice this silly error